# Ошибка с логическим именем в БД

Tags: mysql, база-данных, sql-server

Пытаюсь создать бд

```
use master  
go
create database PDA_UNIVER on primary
( name = N'PDA_UNIVER', filename = N'D:\BDs\Lab4\PDA_UNIVER.mdf', 
   size = 5120Kb, maxsize=10240Kb, filegrowth=1024Kb),
( name = N'PDA_UNIVER', filename = N'D:\BDs\Lab4\PDA_UNIVER.ndf', 
   size = 5120Kb, maxsize=10240Kb, filegrowth=10%),

filegroup G1
( name = N'PDA_UNIVER11', filename = N'D:\BDs\Lab4\PDA_UNIVER11.ndf', 
   size = 10240Kb, maxsize=15Mb, filegrowth=1Mb),
( name = N'PDA_UNIVER12', filename = N'D:\BDs\Lab4\PDA_UNIVER12.ndf', 
   size = 2Mb, maxsize=5Mb, filegrowth=1Mb),

filegroup G2
( name = N'PDA_UNIVER21', filename = N'D:\BDs\Lab4\PDA_UNIVER21.ndf', 
   size = 5120Kb, maxsize=10240Kb, filegrowth=1024Kb),
( name = N'PDA_UNIVER22', filename = N'D:\BDs\Lab4\PDA_UNIVER22.ndf', 
    size = 2Mb, maxsize=5Mb, filegrowth=1Mb)

log on
( name = N'PDA_UNIVER_log', filename=N'D:\BDs\Lab4\PDA_UNIVER_log.ldf',       
   size=5Mb,  maxsize=UNLIMITED, filegrowth=1Mb)
```

Ошибка: Сообщение 1828, уровень 16, состояние 5, строка 3.
Логическое имя файла "PDA_UNIVER" уже используется. Выберите другое имя.
Ну и естественно такой бд нет[image: Список бд]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка прямо вам говорит на совпадение имен в первой инструкции.
Измените **имя файла** в первой инструкции:

```
create database PDA_UNIVER on primary
( name = N'PDA_UNIVER1', filename = N'D:\BDs\Lab4\PDA_UNIVER1.mdf', 
   size = 5120Kb, maxsize=10240Kb, filegrowth=1024Kb),
( name = N'PDA_UNIVER2', filename = N'D:\BDs\Lab4\PDA_UNIVER2.ndf', 
   size = 5120Kb, maxsize=10240Kb, filegrowth=10%),
```